Logitech G-hub lua script
Is it possible to find a workaround for this?
I know that M and N are no G-Keys but I would like to to have two different key sequences depending on the last key input
I have no idea where to start to be honest.
-- Variable to track the last key pressed
local lastKeyPressed = nil

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event == "G_PRESSED" then
        if arg == 77 then -- Direct key code for "M"
            lastKeyPressed = "m"
        elseif arg == 78 then -- Direct key code for "N"
            lastKeyPressed = "n"
        end
    end

    -- Check if the scroll wheel button is pressed to activate the macro
    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 3 then -- Assuming middle mouse button (scroll wheel) is used
        QP()
    end
end

function QP()
    local leanDuration = 25 -- Duration to hold lean in milliseconds
    local pauseDuration = 40 -- Pause between actions in milliseconds

    if lastKeyPressed == "n" then
        -- If N was the last key, press M then N
        PressKey("m")
        Sleep(leanDuration)
        ReleaseKey("m")
        Sleep(pauseDuration)

        PressKey("n")
        Sleep(leanDuration)
        ReleaseKey("n")

    elseif lastKeyPressed == "m" then
        -- If M was the last key, press N then M
        PressKey("n")
        Sleep(leanDuration)
        ReleaseKey("n")
        Sleep(pauseDuration)

        PressKey("m")
        Sleep(leanDuration)
        ReleaseKey("m")
    else
        -- Default action if no key has been pressed yet (optional)
        PressKey("n")
        Sleep(leanDuration)
        ReleaseKey("n")

        Sleep(pauseDuration)

        PressKey("m")
        Sleep(leanDuration)
        ReleaseKey("m")
    end
    lastKeyPressed = nil
end


Please do not tag span. Have a look at [ask]

This is impossible. LGS/GHub is unable to see which usual keys (digits, letters) user is pressing/releasing, this is on purpose to avoid being able to write a keylogger in Lua.  GHub scripts are subject to share between users, so they must be safe.  Only mouse buttons (on a Logitech mouse), G-keys (on a Logitech keyboard) and modifier keys (Ctrl/Alt/Shift on any keyboard) can be seen by a Lua script.

According to the documentation, getting keyboard inputs should be possible, but I can't get them to work - Perhaps due to my keyboard not being from Logitech. Either way, to answer your question, I would use modifiers such as Alt, Shift or Ctrl. Here's an example:
-- Variables
local leanDuration = 25
local pauseDuration = 40

local function Press(key1, key2)
    PressKey(key1)
    Sleep(leanDuration)
    ReleaseKey(key1)
    Sleep(pauseDuration)

    PressKey(key2)
    Sleep(leanDuration)
    ReleaseKey(key2)
end

function OnEvent(event, arg)

    -- Abort if not MMB pressed
    if event ~= "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" or arg ~= 3 then return end

    -- Get button modifier
    -- local lalt = IsModifierPressed("lalt") -- Left Alt
    -- local ralt = IsModifierPressed("ralt") -- Right Alt
    -- local alt = IsModifierPressed("alt") -- Either Alt
    -- local lshift = IsModifierPressed("lshift") -- Left Shift
    -- local rshift = IsModifierPressed("rshift") -- Right Shift
    -- local shift = IsModifierPressed("shift") -- Either Shift
    -- local lctrl = IsModifierPressed("lctrl") -- Left CTRL
    -- local rctrl = IsModifierPressed("rctrl") -- Right CTRL
    local ctrl = IsModifierPressed("ctrl") -- Either CTRL

    -- Alternatively, use lock keys
    -- local scrolllock = IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock")
    -- local capslock = IsKeyLockOn("capslock")
    -- local numlock = IsKeyLockOn("numlock")

    -- Control is pressed
    if ctrl then
        Press("m", "n")
    else
        Press("n", "m")
    end
end

If this isn't exactly something that can help you, then your best bet would be to use something like AutoHotkey.
